# use reduce instead of for loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, ecmascript-6

I want to convert this code to use reduce instead of for loop.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 6];
var add = 0;
var r = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
 add = 0;
 for (var j = 0; j < i; j++) {
   add += a[j];
  }
  if (a[i] > add) {
  r.push(a[i]);
  }
}
console.log(r); //  => [ 1, 2, 30 ]
```

How we can get same out put using reduce?

Comment: did you try something related to reduce?

Comment: what is the logic in output [1,2,30]

Comment: `a.splice(0,a.length/2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) which collects the sum of the previous items and take it for a check if the value has to pushed to the result set.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 6],
    result = [];

array.reduce((r, a) => (a > r && result.push(a), r + a), 0);

console.log(result); // [1, 2, 30]
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd use `.filter()`, which performs a reduce specific to reducing a set to a smaller subset of values. And use `.reduce()` inside the filter callback to sum the numbers to that point.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 6];
var r = a.filter((n, i, arr) =>
  n > arr.slice(0, i).reduce((s, nn) => s + nn, 0)
)
console.log(r); //  => [ 1, 2, 30 ]
```

---

The inner `.reduce()` is actually somewhat redundant since it's just summing an extra value each time. To avoid this, you can reference an outer variable and continue to add to it.

```js
var a = [1, 2, 30, 4, 5, 6];
var s = 0;
var r = a.filter((n, i, arr) => {
  s = i && (s + arr[i-1]);
  return n > s
})
console.log(r); //  => [ 1, 2, 30 ]
```